# How to switch to the default global planner when the custom global fails to make a plan

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, ros-kinetic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried setting the parameter "/move_base/base_global_planner" as "global_planner/GlobalPlanner" when my custom planner fails to make a plan and return false in the function "makePlan" . But still keeps calling the same custom planner instead of the "global_planner/globalPlanner".

I have written below a piece of code from my custom global planner in the makePlan function,

```
    bool success = client.call(srv);
    if (!success)
    {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM_THROTTLE(1, "Failed to call service planner");
        n.setParam("move_base/base_global_planner","global_planner/GlobalPlanner");
        return false;
    }
```

Please help me out on this, or any other alternative ways of switching the global planner.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301361/i-am-making-a-custom-global-planner,-i-want-to-switch-to-the-default-global-planner-when-the-custom-global-fails-to-make-a-plan.-can-you-guys-help-me-out-on-this?/) by [chandra8992](https://answers.ros.org/users/37128/chandra8992/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't do this by setting a parameter -- you need to use dynamic_reconfigure to change the planner at runtime.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chandra8992](https://answers.ros.org/users/37128/chandra8992/) on 2018-08-24**:
thanks, but actually I want to switch the global planner automatically, so is there any other way. I guess using dynamic reconfigure we can only change it manually. Please update on this.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2018-08-24**:
You can programmatically call dynamic_reconfigure -- it has an API -- it's just a service call underneath. You would simply replace your n.setParam() line with the proper call to the dynamic_reconfigure interface.

**Comment by [chandra8992](https://answers.ros.org/users/37128/chandra8992/) on 2018-08-25**:
Thanks. I will try it out.